# Swift: Getting an NSException trying to detect tap on a UITextField

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UITextField with a default input 0. When the user taps on it, I want that 0 to disappear so the user can type their own input.

Here is my attempt:

```
@IBOutlet weak var factInput: UITextField!

func removeDefaultInput(textField: UITextField) -> Void {
    factInput.text = ""
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    factInput.text = "0"

    factInput.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("removeDefaultInput:")), for: UIControlEvents.editingDidBegin)


    keyboardDownOnTapGesture()
}
```

However, the app crashes when I tap on the UITextField and this is the error I'm getting:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

And XCode brings me to this line

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Replace `Selector(("removeDefaultInput:"))` with `#selector(removeDefaultInput(textField:))`

Comment: better idea is defining selector for event in storyboard as actions

Answer (score 1):

Is this Swift 3? If yes, then it's

```
#selector(removeDefaultInput(_:))
```

and the corresponding method is

```
func removeDefaultInput(_ textField: UITextField)
```

But why do you add the action programmatically since the text field is designed in IB?
Better use an `IBAction`, then you could resolve the problems at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways to achieve what you wish to do.

First and foremost is adding a placeholder that by default has value *0*. And if you want to check if the user has typed anything just check-

```
if(factInput.text == ""){
     //no text added by user and just pass 0 value instead
}
```

**OR**

If you want to display *0* initially for some requirement, you could just override the `UITextFieldDelegate` methods that let you know if the user has begun editing.

**Note:** Make sure your class conforms to the `UITextFieldDelegate`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    factInput.text = "0"

    keyboardDownOnTapGesture()
}


func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    if(textField.text == "0"){

        textField.text = ""
    }
}
```